# Not able to post comment in android app to my wordpress site?

Tags: android, wordpress, android-studio, android-fragments, retrofit

I'm developing an app for my Wordpress site. I'm using REST API & RETROFIT library. I have encountered an error showing you must to logged in to post a comment. But in web version, I don't require log in to post comment.
Find my code below.

Activity to write comment using Dialog Fragment

**WriteACommentFragment.java**

```
public class WriteACommentFragment extends DialogFragment {
private int clickedPostId;
private int commentId;
private EditText edtAuthorName, edtAuthorEmail, edtAuthorComment;

private Activity mActivity;
private boolean commentSuccessful = false;
private String authorName;
private String authorEmail;
private String authorComment;

public static interface OnCompleteListener {
    public abstract void onComplete(Boolean isCommentSuccessful, CommentsAndReplies commentsAndReplies);
}

private OnCompleteListener mListener;

public static WriteACommentFragment newInstance(int clickedPostId, int commentId) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(AppConstant.ARG_CLICKED_POST_ID, clickedPostId);
    args.putInt(AppConstant.ARG_COMMENT_ID, commentId);
    WriteACommentFragment fragment = new WriteACommentFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.mActivity = activity;

    try {
        this.mListener = (OnCompleteListener) activity;
    } catch (final ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
    }

}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_comment, null);

    initVar();
    initView(rootView);
    initFunctionality();

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
            .setView(rootView)
            .setTitle(R.string.write_a_comment)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    authorName = edtAuthorName.getText().toString().trim();
                    authorEmail = edtAuthorEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    authorComment = edtAuthorComment.getText().toString().trim();

                     AppPreference.getInstance(mActivity).setString(PrefKey.KEY_EMAIL, authorEmail);
                     AppPreference.getInstance(mActivity).setString(PrefKey.KEY_NAME, authorName);

                    if (commentId == AppConstant.THIS_IS_COMMENT) {
                        sendComment(authorName, authorEmail, authorComment);

                    } else {
                        sendReply(authorName, authorEmail, authorComment);
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (dialogInterface != null) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            })
            .create();
}

public void initVar() {
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        clickedPostId = getArguments().getInt(AppConstant.ARG_CLICKED_POST_ID);
        commentId = getArguments().getInt(AppConstant.ARG_COMMENT_ID);
    }
}

public void initView(View rootView) {
    edtAuthorName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_author_name);
    edtAuthorEmail = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_author_email);
    edtAuthorComment = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_author_comment);
}

public void initFunctionality() {
    edtAuthorName.setText(AppPreference.getInstance(mActivity).getString(PrefKey.KEY_NAME));
    edtAuthorEmail.setText(AppPreference.getInstance(mActivity).getString(PrefKey.KEY_EMAIL));
}

private void sendReply(String authName, String authEmail, String authComment) {

    ApiUtils.getApiInterface().postAReply(authName, authEmail, authComment, clickedPostId, commentId).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                commentSuccessful = true;
                showReturnMessage(mActivity.getString(R.string.successful_reply));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            showReturnMessage(mActivity.getString(R.string.error_message));
        }
    });

}

private void sendComment(String authName, String authEmail, String authComment) {

    ApiUtils.getApiInterface().postAComment(authName, authEmail, authComment, clickedPostId).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                commentSuccessful = true;
                showReturnMessage(mActivity.getString(R.string.successful_comment));
            } else {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                    showReturnMessage(jObjError.getString(AppConstant.COMMENT_MESSAGE));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            showReturnMessage(mActivity.getString(R.string.error_message));
        }
    });
}

public void showReturnMessage(String messageText) {
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, messageText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (authorName.isEmpty()) {
        authorName = mActivity.getString(R.string.author_name);
    }

    CommentsAndReplies commentsAndReplies = new CommentsAndReplies(
            AppConstant.COMMENT_ID,
            AppConstant.COMMENT_PARENT_ID,
            authorName,
            new SimpleDateFormat(AppConstant.COMMENT_DATE_FORMAT).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()),
            new Content(authorComment),
            new AuthorAvaterUrl(null));
    mListener.onComplete(commentSuccessful, commentsAndReplies);
}
}
```

All app constant is declared in this file

**AppConstant.java**

```
public class AppConstant {

    public static final String EMPTY = " ";

    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_URL = "url";
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_POST_ID = "post_id";
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_POST = "post";
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_ALL_COMMENT = "all_comment";
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_ALL_ZERO_PARENT_COMMENT = "zero_parent_comments";
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_CLICKED_COMMENT = "clicked_comment";
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_DIALOG_FRAGMENT = "dialog_fragment";
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_SHOULD_DIALOG_OPEN = "should_dialog_open";
    public static final int THIS_IS_COMMENT = -1;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_COMMENT = 0;
    public static final String BUNDLE_KEY_COMMENT_STATUS = "comment_success_status";
    public static final int DEFAULT_CATEGORY_ID = -1;
    public static final int MAX_VALUE = 999;
    public static final String DOT = ".";

    public static final String ARG_CLICKED_POST_ID = "clicked_post_id";
    public static final String ARG_COMMENT_ID = "comment_id";
    public static final String COMMENT_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String COMMENT_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
    public static final Double COMMENT_ID = 1000.0;
    public static final Double COMMENT_PARENT_ID = 0.0;
    public static final int DEFAULT_PAGE = 1;
 }
```

My app preference key
**PrefKey.java**

```
public class PrefKey {
    public static final String APP_PREF_NAME = "METO";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BINGO!!!
Found a solution to my problem.
I was trying to comment using WP REST API as anonymously which was restricted.
My android code was fine with no errors.
I did modification in my WordPress current theme's ***function.php*** file

```
function filter_rest_allow_anonymous_comments() {
    return true;
}
add_filter('rest_allow_anonymous_comments','filter_rest_allow_anonymous_comments');
```

Added above PHP code in function.php for filtering WP REST request to comment anonymously.

It's working fine.